# HAPI SSL error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, hapi.js, tls1.2

I have a Hapi server which works fine on HTTP. I need to make this work over HTTPS. I have a certificate which we bought from COMODO.

My Key

```
 -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
 MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQDGyXFDz/pSzMxO
 ...
 g7N2PgtU9nhM7eYhQmhjB+4=
 -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

My Certificate

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFbDCCBFSgAwIBAgIRAK3oQPHzO66FR3iLafOh2JkwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
...
pvWiUJabAat2O+hexjv55O4RkfQ13aIKo1Z7VeWyNQdEPaSCOFtteC4a3WelWcZ7
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

(have also tried this with a combined root certificate bundle with the same problem)

Edit: Both the certificates and the key are in the PEM format and not the DER format. There are also no problems with line endings.

My Server Code

```
var tls = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
};

var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
    address: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 443,
    tls: tls,
    routes: { cors: { origin: ['*'] }, validate: { options: { abortEarly: false } } }
});
```

I end up with the following error when trying to start the server

```
node server.js

Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Error (native)
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:87:19)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:754:25)
    at new Server (https.js:24:14)
    at Object.exports.createServer (https.js:44:10)
    at new module.exports.internals.Connection.options (W:\project\node_modules\hapi\lib\connection.js:89:74)
    at internals.Server.connection (W:\project\node_modules\hapi\lib\server.js:121:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (W:\project\server.js:98:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
```

What is going on? how do I fix this? 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you concatenate the various certificates together? https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/789/37/certificate-installation-nginx

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837161/openssl-pem-routinespem-read-biono-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-truste

Comment: Also try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630544/cant-get-private-key-with-openssl-no-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-any-p

Comment: Yes, I have a concatenate certificate (I mentioned this above as a "combined root certificate bundle", for lack of a better term), using which I have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I had looked through both already. Both the certificates and the key are in the PEM format and not the DER format. There are also no problems with line endings.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue, my configuration is different as I'm supplying the cert and key as a string (this is dev only). I was getting this same error because I linearized my key from a text editor which stripped out the new line (\n) characters. As soon as I added those \n characters back into my string, it worked just fine. Which got me thinking about your issue....

I tested your `fs.readFileSync('server.key')` (yes my server.key is in PEM format) code using my certificate and key and I noticed that without specifying an encoding, the file data was coming back as a byte array.
`<Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d ....`

However, specifying an encoding `fs.readFileSync('server.key', 'utf-8')` did give me back the certificate data as a human readable string.

I'd try updating your readFileSync calls to include an encoding like 'utf-8' - it could be why hapi can't understand your certificate data.

Hope this helps!