# how to convert ssl private-key.txt to private.key extension

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, openssl

I got pvt-key.txt, certificate.crt and bundle.crt files from godaddy.
I am setting ssl for node js backend using `https` options

```
var httpsoptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("pvt-key.txt"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("certificate.crt")
};
```

but it is not working.

`Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`

I also converted .txt to .pem but there is same error. if I generate key from this command

`openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey2.key -out certificate2.crt`

then it works. I think there should be `.key` extension instead of `.pem` or `.txt`. Please help me to convert file into `.key` extension. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extension of the file doesn't matter so much, but the contents of the file do. I suspect node wants a PEM encoded private key. You can convert a DER encoded private key to a PEM one like this:

```
openssl rsa -in pvt-key.txt -outform pem -out pvt-key.key
```

Comment: `unable to load Private Key`
`140456286238464:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:691:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY` I'm getting this error.

Comment: @SureshMaurya i'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't find any solution. so I have set ssl with apache2 and used nodejs backend with proxy

Comment: first i did next in my privatkey.txt (get read of BOM): https://stackoverflow.com/a/54026652/3877632 and then i started openssl rsa -in pvt-key.txt -outform pem -out pvt-key.key

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this, @vcsjones provided the solution I was able to use.

> openssl rsa -in pvt-key.txt -outform pem -out pvt-key.key

But, I got the same error as others:
`Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY.`

My fix was found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54026652.

> Open the key file in Notepad++ and verify the encoding. If it says UTF-8-BOM then change it to UTF-8. Save the file and try again.