# .pem file format in wireshark

Tags: openssl, wireshark, private-key, pem

I've spent the whole day trying to decrypt some SSL packets on Wireshark using my .pem certificate but in vain.

I got the certificate using mitmproxy.

The header and footer of my .pme certificate are the following:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When I import the certificate on Wireshark (**Edit > preferences > protocols > ssl > Edit**) so I can decrypt SSL packets I get the following error:

> Can't load private key from /home/user/Téléchargements/mitmproxy-ca.pem: can't import pem data: The requested data were not available.

Many resources like [generate a root certificat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460035/unable-to-load-private-key-pem-routinespem-read-biono-start-linepem-lib-c6/42901864) say that I need to have the following header and footer so that Wireshark manages to parse the private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So did I; I've modified my header and footer, but Wireshark is still incapable of loading the private key.

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the header and footer doesn't change the contents.

If you started off with the certificate (which only contains the public key) then changing the header and footer to `BEGIN/END RSA PRIVATE KEY` doesn't change the file to a private key.

You need to get hold of the original private key file.

Also, if you stop and think about it, a certificate is *public* information.  If all that were needed to decrypt a TLS/SSL connection was a certificate then all the secure communications in the world would be compromised.

Comment: This is so right, thank you for your response. But do you have any idea about how I can decrypt the SSL packets on Wireshark? knowing that I only have the certificate generated by mimproxy.

Comment: Read my last sentence again.  If you could decrypt it with a public certificate, then I could also decrypt it and so could all your foes.  You cannot decrypt with a certificate by design.  It's how asymmetric encryption works.  You __must__ have the private key in order to decrypt.